# Moving unallocated space from Extended partition to create a Primary partition

Tags: filesystems, partition, gparted

This is my partition structure :

[image: Partition List]

I want to create another primary partition from that unallocated space.
If I shrink sda2 to a size less than what I needed for to create another primary partition, will it move entire extended partition to right or just slices off extended space from it as it is contiguous ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it will not move the entire extended partition nor make the space contigious.

Although in theory the extended partition could just be recreated with the same 
logical partitions, that would mean that the entries stay in place (with some  zero size first, logical partition), or you would have to rearange the Extended partition information. Both that would free up space between sda1 and sda2, but I don't know about any tools that will do that for you, and I cannot recommend experimenting and possible loosing access to the data.

As this is only a small 300Gb disc, I recommend making a backup of all the data on the medium you normally use for the backup of your drive, then boot from USB/CD, re-partition to your liking and restoring everything.

Answer (score 1):

About a month ago, I did exactly what you are asking via PartedMagic (LiveCD) in separate steps:

Select entire extended partition border, shrink to the right (or calculate offset/size) and apply/commit.

Now reboot (1st reboot).  If I recall, the space  was still unallocated except it was now *outside* of the extended partition. i.e. a 2nd primary. Take note, a small partition of a few megabytes was created inside the resized extended partition, with a new partition ID. Keep a close eye on your partition IDs!

After confirming the operating system(s) booted and all partitions were intact and mountable, I again utilized PartedMagic to create/allocate the 2nd primary partition, applied the change and rebooted.

It's worth noting that I did this on a triple-boot system (WinXP, Win7, PCLinuxOS).  If you have Win7 or XP, I strongly suggest you boot after each change and let it run it's chkdsk.

Comment: I strongly recommend making a full backup of the **complete disk** before trying something like this. If it works out fine, you save yourself the restore time. If not ....

Comment: thanks. I shrank it without taking backup and then created FreeBSD fs (ada0s3) and ufs (ada0s3a) in unallocated space everything went fine :) - not sure if that is intentional that extended partition still has the same id sda2 even if it is bellow the new slice which keeps grub from not being corrupted to load other OSs.